# GridLayout not filling rows evenly (Android)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to get an evenly filled grid using GridLayout (API 21). Filling in the horizontal direction works fine using layout_columnWeight attribute. The same with layout_rowWeight attribute fails (see screenshot) [image]. I am pretty clueless.. It seems like the both attributes don't work in the same way.

Also even more simplified layouts show the same behavior (1 row x 2 columns works, 2 rows x 1 column fails). Also explicitly adding of layout_row and layout_column attributes don't change anything.

Please don't answer "use linearLayout". I want to get it working with the GridLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#0099cc" 
    tools:context=".Locomotion">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="north west"
            android:id="@+id/textViewNW"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
            android:background="#fe4141" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="north east"
            android:id="@+id/textViewNE"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
            android:background="#51f328" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="south west"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSW"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
            android:background="#fefe00" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="south east"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSE"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
            android:background="#0080f0" />

    </GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was difficult. Had to get creative to solve it. Basically my solution was to nest GridLayouts for each col with a master GridLayout for 1 row. Also each col GridLayout must be in orientation="verticle" with width/height = "wrap_content"

Result:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".Locomotion">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#fe4141"
                android:text="north west"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#fefe00"
                android:text="south west"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </GridLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#51f328"
                android:text="north east"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="#0080f0"
                android:text="south east"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But is there really no "cleaner" approach? In this case a nested GridLayout isn't better than nested linear layouts...

Comment: I can't find a "cleaner" way of doing it. The fill in the height direction doesn't seem to work the same way as it does in the width direction. This is really the best way I've found.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite a pain :(

Comment: Sure thing. Don't forget to mark it as answer and +1 it. :)

Comment: Is there a way to set the `layout_columnWeight` on the `GridLayout` so that its set on all children?